# How to freshly install ubuntu 12.04 deleting both ubuntu 12.10 and windows xp

Tags: 12.04, windows

In my laptop, I have both windows XP and ubuntu 12.10. Now, I wish to **delete** both and freshly install **Ubuntu 12.04**.. I've already taken backups of my data.. Now I just wish to remove the OS and then install **Ubuntu 12.04** booting from a USB drive.

Any help will be highly appreciative.

Thanks
Kalyan

Answer (score 1):

just follow the official guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

In the "Installation Type" menu, choose the option "**Erase disk and install Ubuntu**".

Follow all the next steps until reboot.

You're done !

Cheers,
ponsfrilus